# How to concatenate three string in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have three string and I want them to concatenate but they are not concatenating. I am using this code.

I want my last string to display like this:

> Cerenia Results 12Jun 2012.pdf

like this

```
NSString *fileName = @"Cerenia Results";

NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date]; 

NSString*extention=@".pdf";


NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cerenia Results_%@ [%@].pdf", extension];
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**General case** : to concatenate all three strings you should use

```
NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", fileName, str, extension];
```

**Your case**:

You can add any formatting you like such as inserting characters in between (to get the results you are after >> Cerenia Results 12Jun 2012.pdf)

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMMyyyy"]
NSString* fileName = @"Cerenia Results";
NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString* extension = @"pdf";
NSString* strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@.%@", fileName, str, extension];
```

Comment: thanks for this, I was missing the stringWithFormat portion to preformat a url string.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMMyyyy"]
 NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date]; 
 NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cerenia Results %@.pdf",str];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append string using "**stringByAppendingFormat**" ...

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMMyyyy"]
NSString* fileName = @"Cerenia Results";
NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString* extension = @".pdf";
NSString* strRR = [[fileName stringByAppendingFormat:str]stringByAppendingFormat:extension];
```